# How to save data in a .txt file in C programming

Tags: c, file-io

I'm a beginner and I'm having trouble with a project for school. I have the outline of the program working fine. What I am having trouble with is saving new data to my players.txt file.

If I play the game with a player, and they win 10 points, I want that to save to the .txt file and show when I look at the top 5's balance or if I close the program and open it and play with that player again.

Currently it is only saving the winnings/losings data while I stay in the play() function. Then it reverts back to the original numbers in the players.txt file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char Name[20];
    int Balance;
    int Gain;
    } Person;
Person player[10];

//Function Declaration to get data for ingame
Person GetPlayerData(const char* name, Person *p);
//Function Declaration to exit to main menu when finished with game
void mainMenu(void);

//Opens file player.txt and puts it into array of persons: Person player[10]
void loadPlayer()
{
//initialize an array for players with room for 10 player's information


//opens file with pointer fptr
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("players.txt", "r");

//prints error if file doesn't exist
if(fptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Error loading player.txt\n");
}

//Runs through each line of the file, assigning name, balance and gain to the array player[]
int i=0;
while (fscanf(fptr, "%s%d%d", player[i].Name, &player[i].Balance, &player[i].Gain) != EOF)
{
    i++;
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", player[i].Name, player[i].Balance, player[i].Gain);
}

fclose(fptr);   
}


//GetPlayerData function

Person GetPlayerData(const char* name, Person *p) {

 int j = 0;
 for (;;) {

      if (strcmp(name, p[j].Name) == 0) {

          return p[j];

      }

      j++;

 }

}

//Play function
void play(void) {

 char name[20];

 int bal = 0;

 int dice1, dice2, sumofDice;

 printf("Enter your name: ");

 scanf("%s", &name);

 Person playerDetails = GetPlayerData(name, player);

 getchar();

 //Begin Game

 while (1) {


      printf("Press Enter to Roll the dice.\n");

      getchar();

      dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;

      dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;

      sumofDice = dice1 + dice2;



      printf("The values of the dices are %d and %d whose sum is %d.\n", dice1, dice2, sumofDice);

      if (sumofDice == 7 || sumofDice == 11) {

          playerDetails.Balance = playerDetails.Balance + 10;

          printf("You win the game. Your current balance is %d.\n", playerDetails.Balance);

          char userChoice;

          printf("Play another game? y/n ");

          scanf("%s", &userChoice);

          if (userChoice == 'y') {

               getchar();

               continue;

          }

          else {

               break;

          }

      }

      else if (sumofDice == 2 || sumofDice == 3 || sumofDice == 12) {

          playerDetails.Balance = playerDetails.Balance - 1;

          printf("You lose. Your current balance is %d.\n", playerDetails.Balance);

          char userChoice;

          printf("Play another game? y/n ");

          scanf("%s", &userChoice);

          if (userChoice == 'y') {

               getchar();

               continue;

          }

          else {

               getchar();

               break;

          }

      }

      else {

          int point = sumofDice;

          //Continuing the game after your point is declared

          while (1) {

               printf("Press Enter to Roll the dice.\n");

               getchar();

               int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;

               int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;

               int sumofDice = dice1 + dice2;

               printf("The values of the dice are %d and %d whose sum is %d.\n", dice1, dice2, 
sumofDice);

               if (sumofDice == point) {

                    playerDetails.Balance = playerDetails.Balance + 10;

                    printf("You win the game. Your current balance is %d.\n", playerDetails.Balance);

                    char userChoice;

                    printf("Play another game? y/n ");

                    scanf("%s", &userChoice);

                    if (userChoice == 'y') {

                         getchar();

                         continue;

                    }

                    else {

                         break;

                    }

               }

               else if (sumofDice == 7) {

                    playerDetails.Balance = playerDetails.Balance - 1;

                    printf("You lose. Your current balance is %d.\n", playerDetails.Balance);

                    char userChoice;

                    printf("Play another game? y/n ");

                    scanf("%s", &userChoice);

                    if (userChoice == 'y') {

                         getchar();

                         continue;

                    }

                    else {

                         break;

                    }

               }

               else {

                    continue;

               }

          }

          break;

      }

 }

 getchar();

 mainMenu();

}

void topBalance()
{
int  firstLoc, i;
int firstVal = 0;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if ((player[i].Balance) > firstVal)
    {
        firstVal = player[i].Balance;
        firstLoc = i;
    }
}

int secondLoc;
int secondVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Balance) > secondVal) && ((player[i].Balance) < firstVal))
    {
        secondVal = player[i].Balance;
        secondLoc = i;
    }
}

int thirdLoc;
int thirdVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Balance) > thirdVal) && ((player[i].Balance) < secondVal))
    {
        thirdVal = player[i].Balance;
        thirdLoc = i;
    }
}

int forthLoc;
int forthVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Balance) > forthVal) && ((player[i].Balance) < thirdVal))
    {
        forthVal = player[i].Balance;
        forthLoc = i;
    }
}

int fifthLoc;
int fifthVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Balance) > fifthVal) && ((player[i].Balance) < forthVal))
    {
        fifthVal = player[i].Balance;
        fifthLoc = i;
    }
}

printf("1st Place %s \t%d\n", player[firstLoc].Name, player[firstLoc].Balance);
printf("2nd Place %s \t%d\n", player[secondLoc].Name, player[secondLoc].Balance);
printf("3rd Place %s \t%d\n", player[thirdLoc].Name, player[thirdLoc].Balance);
printf("4th Place %s \t%d\n", player[forthLoc].Name, player[forthLoc].Balance);
printf("5th Place %s \t%d\n", player[fifthLoc].Name, player[fifthLoc].Balance);
}

void topGain()
{
int  firstLoc, i;
int firstVal = 0;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if ((player[i].Gain) > firstVal)
    {
        firstVal = player[i].Gain;
        firstLoc = i;
    }
}

int secondLoc;
int secondVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Gain) > secondVal) && ((player[i].Gain) < firstVal))
    {
        secondVal = player[i].Gain;
        secondLoc = i;
    }
}

int thirdLoc;
int thirdVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Gain) > thirdVal) && ((player[i].Gain) < secondVal))
    {
        thirdVal = player[i].Gain;
        thirdLoc = i;
    }
}

int forthLoc;
int forthVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Gain) > forthVal) && ((player[i].Gain) < thirdVal))
    {
        forthVal = player[i].Gain;
        forthLoc = i;
    }
}

int fifthLoc;
int fifthVal = 0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (((player[i].Gain) > fifthVal) && ((player[i].Gain) < forthVal))
    {
        fifthVal = player[i].Gain;
        fifthLoc = i;
    }
}

printf("1st Place %s \t%d\n", player[firstLoc].Name, player[firstLoc].Gain);
printf("2nd Place %s \t%d\n", player[secondLoc].Name, player[secondLoc].Gain);
printf("3rd Place %s \t%d\n", player[thirdLoc].Name, player[thirdLoc].Gain);
printf("4th Place %s \t%d\n", player[forthLoc].Name, player[forthLoc].Gain);
printf("5th Place %s \t%d\n", player[fifthLoc].Name, player[fifthLoc].Gain);
}


void mainMenu()
{
int menuSellect;

printf("\n--------Main Menu--------");
printf("\n0) Top Up Account");  
printf("\n1) Play");
printf("\n2) Top 5 Players by Balance");
printf("\n3) Top 5 Players by Winnings");
printf("\n4) Exit Game");
printf("\n-------------------------\n");

//prompt user to pick a menu item 0 to 3
printf("Please Enter a Number for a Valid Menu Item: ");
scanf("%d", &menuSellect);
printf("\n\n");

//switch statement controlls what menu item is going to be sellected
switch (menuSellect)
{
    case 0:
        printf("Top Up Account\n");
        mainMenu();
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Play\n");
        play();
        mainMenu();
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Top 5 Players by Balance\n");
        topBalance();
        mainMenu();
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Top 5 Players by Winnings\n");
        topGain();
        mainMenu();
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Exitting Game\n");
        exit(0);

    //deffault catches any errors and prints the main menu a second time
    deffault:
        printf("Invalid Menu Option\n");
        mainMenu();
        break;
}
}
 void main()
{
loadPlayer();
mainMenu();

}
```

Comment: you haven't written a save function. look up fprintf, start with a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through this code, I can see where you open the "players.txt" file and read  the data in to your program using fscanf. What you are missing is code that will write this data back out again, either when you exit or after a game completes.
Investigate opening the file for write and then using something like fprintf to save the data out.

Note that you are using "r" to open the file for reading. When you write out you will need to use one of "w" or "a", depending on whether you are adding a new line to the file or rewriting the whole thing.